# Transfer a file via FTP to another server using PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I have a file in my server and I want to transfer it to another server using FTP. The file I have is in the same folder as my PHP page.

The code I am using does not work

```
$my_connection = ftp_connect("tel.bpo.fr", 21) or exit('Erreur : connexion au serveur FTP impossible.');
ftp_login($my_connection, "AD_185", "UYTREE");

$from = "test.csv" ; 
$to = "/entree/test.csv" ; 

if ($my_connection && ftp_put($my_connection, $to, $from,  FTP_BINARY)){
    echo "good <br/>" ;
}else {
    echo "erreur";
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question ... "Does not work" is not a question. What does that mean exactly? What error message do you get? What happens?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work .

Comment: You should test the connection separate from the transfer. Your not going to know witch has failed. You really should be using sftp with key exchange.

Answer (score 0):

What does not work? Looks like Windows / Paths ...
To enable ftp on Windows you have to add the line:

```
extension=php_ftp.dll
```

to your php.ini to resolve PHP errors that tell you PHP FTP functions are not defined; the line isn't in there (where, many things are and are just commented out).

Comment: Do not know why some one has downwoted that. For me that was the answer! Thank you @peter